# Subsequential Limits of a Conditionally Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\sum_{x=1}^\infty a_n$ be a conditionally convergent series of real numbers. Let $(s_n)$ be the sequence of $n$-th partial sums. Let $S$ be the set of all subsequential limits of $(s_n)\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Is there anything that can be said about $S$? Does it equal $\mathbb{R}$ by any consequence of the Riemann Series Theorem?

Comment: My issue is that a reordering doesn't really count as a subsequence, does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$s_n$ tends to a finite limit $s$. So all subsequence of $\{s_n\}$ converge to $s$ and the set of limits of subsequences is $\{s\}$.

Comment: Why does $s_n$ tend to a finite limit? Doesn't only $|s_n|$ converge?

Comment: By definition a series converges iff the sequence of partial sums $\{s_n\}$ tends to a  finite limit. In this case the series is given to be convergent. It is not absolutely convergent, but that has no consequence.